# Блокировка только одной строки

Tags: sql, oracle

Какие строки заблокируются в запросе

```
select m.id, m.is_ready from machine m join estar e on m.id = e.machine_id where e.status = 'COMP' FOR UPDATE
```

Интересует блокируется ли строка из таблицы estar и если все таки блокируется как сделать чтобы блокировала только строка из таблицы machine.

Comment: А почему бы не попробовать - `for update of table.col`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для блокировки только записей в одной таблице (или нескольких на выбор, но не всех) можно воспользоваться: `select ... for update of tab1.colnam, tab2.colnam`.

Так будует осуществлена строчная блокировка только таблиц `tab1` и `tab2`.
Какую колонку из существующих в таблице указывать, не играет абсолютно никакого значения.

Т.к. подзапрос выполняется отдельно от основного, строчки таблиц указанных в нём не будут заблокированы. И наоборот, если подзапрос содержит - `for update`, а основной нет, строчки из таблиц основного запроса не будут заблокированны.

Пременимо к запросу из вопроса:

```
select m.id, m.is_ready 
from machine m 
join estar e e.machine_id = on m.id  
where e.status = 'COMP' FOR UPDATE of m.is_ready
;
```

Наглядный пример использующий схему `SH`:

```
select cu.cust_id, cu.cust_last_name, co.country_name
from customers cu
join countries co on co.country_id=cu.country_id
where cu.cust_id = 69
for update
;

select o.object_name, o.object_type, s.sid, s.serial#, s.status
from v$locked_object l
join v$session s on  s.sid = l.session_id
join dba_objects o on o.object_id = l.object_id
;

OBJECT_NAM OBJECT_TYP    SID SERIAL# STATUS
---------- ---------- ------ ------- ----------
CUSTOMERS  TABLE          22   19511 ACTIVE
COUNTRIES  TABLE          22   19511 ACTIVE

2 rows selected.

SQL> rollback;
Rollback complete.

select cu.cust_id, cu.cust_last_name, co.country_name
from customers cu 
join countries co on co.country_id=cu.country_id
where cu.cust_id = 69
for update of cu.cust_income_level
;

--*** повторим выборку текущих блокировок ***

OBJECT_NAM OBJECT_TYP    SID SERIAL# STATUS
---------- ---------- ------ ------- ----------
CUSTOMERS  TABLE          22   19511 ACTIVE

1 row selected.
```

Comment: То что нужно было, спасибо

Comment: Пожалуйста, рад был помочь.

Answer (score 2):

Насколько я понимаю суть работы `FOR UPDATE`, он должен заблокировать все строки, которые считываются в запросе. И неважно - входят ли столбцы из них в набор, который видит конечный пользователь. Если в Вашем случае строка в таблице `estar`, связанная со строкой в `machine` не будет заблокирована, то она может быть изменена до завершения транзакции. А это приведёт к тому что выборка данных станет неактуальна. Не вижу смысла в такой блокировке. Хотя надёжнее всего в Вашем случае проверить как именно реализована работа `FOR UPDATE` в Oracle. Заполните таблицу тестовыми данными, такими чтобы точно знать, что должно заблокироваться. Сделайте свой запрос с `SELECT FOR UPDATE`, но `COMMIT` не делайте. Затем начните параллельно ещё одну транзакцию. В ней попытайтесь обновить строку, которая по Вашим подсчётам должна быть заблокирована. Если вторая транзакция будет ждать, пока в первой `COMMIT` не сделаете - значит я прав и блокировка на estar есть.
P.S. Сделал бы эту проверку сам, но Oracle под рукой нет)

Comment: Да, строка из estar Действительно тоже блокируется, что можно сделать чтобы не блокировалась и она тоже

Comment: @JNat Думаю если таблицу убрать из from это может помочь. проверьте что то вроде `select m.id, m.is_ready
  from machine m
 where m.id IN(select machine_id from estar where e.status = 'COMP') FOR UPDATE`

Comment: Так я думал, но таблица estar очень большая. В итоге надо продумывать другую логику работы с этими таблицами

Comment: @JNat даже интересно - к чему привело то, что советовал Mike в комментарии выше? Блокировка на estar осталась или просто при применении подзапросов просела производительность? Сам подозреваю первое, но интересно, что на практике.

Comment: Только что проверил, строки из таблицы estar не заблокировались.

Comment: @JNat , спасибо. Интересный факт